# what is the coefficient of x in the following expressions

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me out with wether my assumptions are correct with the coefficient of $x$ in the following expressions:

$$   17 - 6x^2 + 2x  $$

I would say the answer is $-4$

$$   12xy - 3x + 4  $$

I would say the answer is $3$ or would you include the $12xy$?

$$    5x^4 + 7x^3 - 11x^2 + 3 $$

I would say the answer is $1$.

Some or all of my answers are wrong could somebody explain why? Thank you.

Comment: Look for an instance of a single $x$ with no power or other variable multiplied by it. The number in front of the $x$ is the coefficient of $x$. Note that subtraction should be viewed as adding a negative number instead. What number could you multiply $x$ by to make it disappear? That's the coefficient when no $x$ is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know the coefficient of $x$, in the first equation is $2$, since you cannot sum $x^2$ and $x$ coefficients.

In the second equation it's, as you say, $-3$.

In the third equation it's $0$ since there's no element with just one $x$.

Comment: It seems I agree with Soph :)

Answer (score 2):

A coefficient is a constant by which a variable is multiplied. In your case the variable is $x$.

- For $$17−6x^2+2x$$ the coefficient of $x$ is 2.
- For $$12xy−3x+4$$ the coefficient of $x$ is -3. We must keep the sign.
- For $$5x^4+7x^3−11x^2+3$$ the coefficient of $x$ is 0. There is no $x$ term.